# How to focus cell in row for adding new record in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, focus

How can I programmatically focus cell in WinForms DataGridView shown highlighted on sample below?

[image]

I can easily set focus to any cell in rows 0~3 but that cell is in row 4 which looks like "virtual" because `dataGridView1.Row(4)` does not exist.

Comment: The code of @OSKM and `dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1 .Rows(4).Cells(0)` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i have quite got your question but does `DataGridView1.NewRowIndex` not work for what you want?

I tried `DataGridView1.Item(0, DataGridView1.NewRowIndex).Selected = True` which seems to do what I think you are trying to achieve.

The code above is on the click event of button 1 and produces the following:

[image: Datagridview with first cell of new row selected]

If you want to 'un-select' any currently selected cell first then precede the above with `If Not IsNothing(DataGridView1.CurrentCell) Then DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected = False`, the `If Not IsNothing...` is to cover the code running where no cell is currently selected.

BTW I don't think you can use `.CurrentCell` for a cell selected on the new row, but you can use `.item`

Comment: `dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1 .Rows(dataGridView1.NewRowIndex).Cells(0)` focuses leftmost cell of row **3** as active cell (instead of leftmost cell in row 4)

Comment: *regarding your edited answer:* OK, that different approach you recently added seems to work instead of using `.CurrentCell`. Thank you.